# Install Octave packages on ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, package, ubuntu-16.04, octave

I tried several commands to install the package `optim` into my Octave in `Ubuntu 16.10` to use the function `xcorr`, but I miserably failed.

Some of these commands were:

```
- sudo apt-get install octave-optim
- sudo apt-get install liboctave-dev
- sudo apt-get install octave-signal
- sudo apt-get install octave-pkg-dev
```

Can somebody explain me or does somebody know how to install the packages in Ubuntu 16?
After running the above-mentioned commands, I restarted Octave but the command `xcorr()` was still returning the error:

> warning: the 'xcorr' function belongs to the signal package from
>   Octave Forge which you have installed but not loaded.  To load the
>   package, run 'pkg load signal' from the Octave prompt.

Unfortunately, 'pkg' returns:

> No command 'pkg' found, did you mean:  Command 'pig' from package
>   'bsdgames' (universe)  Command 'peg' from package 'peg' (universe) 
>   Command 'pki' from package 'pki-tools' (universe)  Command 'pki' from
>   package 'strongswan-starter' (main)  Command 'dpkg' from package
>   'dpkg' (main)  Command 'pg' from package 'util-linux' (main)  Command
>   'ekg' from package 'ekg' (universe)  Command 'ekg' from package
>   'ekg-gtk' (universe) pkg: command not found

Comment: Read your error carefully. "*Run `pkg load signal` from the **Octave** prompt*". Sounds like you ran it on the bash prompt.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you've successfully installed the package anyway, but for future reference, you can also install packages directly within octave using the `pkg` command and specifying the `-forge` option, which downloads them directly from the octaveforge website, e.g. `pkg install image -forge`.

Comment: In general, packages need to be "loaded" before you can use the functions they provide. Write `pkg list` in your **Octave** terminal to see what's installed; if they have an asterisk next to the name it means the package is also *loaded*.

Comment: Guys, you are great. I was completely into the terminal. Thank you all!

Comment: The pleasure is all "ours", hahah. :p

Comment: Tasos and his ego :-P

Answer (score 2):

Please type `pkg load signal` in the Octave command prompt, as you have already have it installed.  To auto-load it everytime you start Octave, create ~/.octaverc file and add the line `pkg load signal` inside the file.

If in future, the pkg that you need is not currently installed, you will need to install it with `pkg install -forge <pkgname>` e.g. `pkg install -forge io`. Similarly, you will need to load it as described earlier.

Hope it helps.