# Octave signal package installation

Tags: matlab, package, installation, octave

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and currently using Octave as a reciprocal to Matlab for signal processing. Everything was fine till I needed to use `medfilt1` function to get the median. Octave generated an error report saying that signal package is not installed on my system. After browsing a bit I found the command

```
 sudo apt-get install octave-signal
```

I ran this command and it showed everything downloaded and installed perfectly. However, if I again run the octave script the error persists:

> warning: the 'medfilt1' function belongs to the signal package from Octave Forge
>   which you have installed but not loaded.  To load the package, run 'pkg
>   load signal' from the Octave prompt.
>
> Please read http://www.octave.org/missing.html to learn how you can
>   contribute missing functionality.
>   warning: called from
>       **unimplemented** at line 524 column 5
>       filter-practice.m at line 8 column 2
>   error: 'medfilt1' undefined near line 8 column 3
>   error: called from
>       filter-practice.m at line 8 column 2

Analyzing the error message I attempted to run `pkg load signal` but the terminal told me that there is no such command.

> command not found: pkg

How can I get the signal package installed on my system?

Comment: Can you show the exact error you're getting trying to load the signal package?

Comment: So when you run `pkg load signal`, that is the message you receive?

Comment: I don't have an ubuntu intall handy to test, but it seems the packagers intend for you not to use the pkg command at all. They've partitioned it off to the `octave-dev` package. You could install that and I imagine it would work, but maybe you could try restarting octave instead and seeing if it's then loaded automatically?

Comment: I've also tried this one out, i.e., restarting the system. Actually I am new to Ubuntu. So I'm looking for a concrete way to install the package. For example running several commands or copy-pasting to directories would do the job for me. Can you help me out?

Comment: Wait, you're not running `pkg load signal` from within octave are you. If not, try that.

Comment: That solved me!

Comment: Cut it from comment, and paste it as an answer. I'll accept it. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pkg` command is actually a part of octave and should be run from within octave, not from a shell terminal.

---

Credit for this answer goes to the members in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490798/install-octave-packages-on-ubuntu-16), but since they similarly came to the conclusion in extended comments and didn't end up posting an answer, maybe this will find some others falling into this trap :)

Answer (score 16):

I'll provide an answer here for future users, even though the post has an accepted answer already, as it's missing all the relevant details **(if you're only interested in how to make a package installed via apt-get to show up on your octave session, see the bit at the end).**

To install one of the packages listed on [Octaveforge](https://octave.sourceforge.io/) (see [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/packages.php) for the full list of available packages), you can download the `.tar.gz` file for the particular package from its respective page (e.g. [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/index.html) for the `signal` package), and then go to that folder and issue the following command at an *octave* terminal:

```
pkg install signal
```

Alternatively and far more conveniently, you can ask octave to download the package directly from Octaveforge and install it, by appending the `-forge` option:

```
pkg install signal -forge
```

You may also want to specify *where* to install such packages if you don't like the default location (typically `~/octave`), using the `pkg prefix` command before installing a package (see documentation for details).

Once a package has been installed, you can query the list of installed packages using the `pkg list` command; 'loaded' packages are noted with an asterisk, e.g on my PC.

```
octave:1> pkg list
Package Name         | Version | Installation directory
---------------------+---------+-----------------------
fuzzy-logic-toolkit  |   0.4.5 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5
              image *|   2.6.1 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/image-2.6.1
                 io  |   2.4.7 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/io-2.4.7
         statistics  |   1.3.0 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/statistics-1.3.0
```

To *load* a package, use the `pkg load` command; any 'dependencies' will be loaded as well automatically, e.g.:

```
octave:2> pkg load statistics
octave:3> pkg list
Package Name         | Version | Installation directory
---------------------+---------+-----------------------
fuzzy-logic-toolkit  |   0.4.5 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5
              image *|   2.6.1 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/image-2.6.1
                 io *|   2.4.7 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/io-2.4.7
         statistics *|   1.3.0 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/statistics-1.3.0
```

---

The above methods are all considered *local* installations. Octave keeps a list of installed packages in files called `octave_packages`, typically found either in your octave installation or your home folder.
**In the case that you've installed packages globally from a repository instead** you will have to let octave know by linking to the appropriate `octave_packages` file, typically `/usr/share/octave/octave_packages`, using the `pkg global_list` command.

For example, I had to install the `odepkg` from the repositories, because the direct option above gave me an error. To have it appear in the list of available packages in octave, you have to specify the presence of such globally installed pkgs:

```
octave:4> pkg global_list /usr/share/octave/octave_packages 
octave:5> pkg list
Package Name         | Version | Installation directory
---------------------+---------+-----------------------
fuzzy-logic-toolkit  |   0.4.5 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5
              image *|   2.6.1 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/image-2.6.1
                 io *|   2.4.7 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/io-2.4.7
             odepkg  |   0.8.5 | /usr/share/octave/packages/odepkg-0.8.5
         statistics *|   1.3.0 | /media/tasos/Gandalf/opt/octave-4.2.1/lib/statistics-1.3.0
```

However, in general, it's probably more useful to install such packages *locally*, as the package versions in the repositories are often out-of-date (and having to do `pkg global_list` every time is a hassle);
I would only install global packages from the linux terminal if a local installation within octave doesn't work for whatever reason (e.g. giving compilation errors).

See the documentation of the `pkg` command for more details, by doing `help pkg` in the octave terminal.