# Cannot load Packages available in share\octave\packages but not listed in share\octave\octave_packages

Tags: installation, octave, package

**The short story**:

In the directory `...\octave-4.2.1\share\octave\packages` there were initially 45 package subdirectories (with `.m` and other files), for instance `financial-0.5.0`.
*But I could not find a way to use them*.

**In more detail**:

I have unzipped [the portable (.zip) version](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/octave-4.2.1-w64.zip) of Octave 4.2.1 64 bit for Windows, at 8:00am (useful info for later), into `C:\Users\user1\DOCUME~1\apps\OCTAVE~1.1` (originally `C:\Users\user1\Documents\apps\octave-4.2.1`).

I have then installed `symbolic-2.6.0` (at 8:19am) with

```
>> pkg install symbolic-2.6.0
```

and this one is now available, e.g.,

```
>> pkg list
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
    symbolic  |   2.6.0 | C:\Users\user1\DOCUME~1\apps\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\packages\symbolic-2.6.0
```

As per [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Installing-and-Removing-Packages.html),

```
>> pkg global_list
C:\Users\user1\DOCUME~1\apps\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\octave_packages
```

gives "the file in which to look for information on globally installed packages".
That file does not have any information on any of the 45 built-in packages. It only has info on `symbolic`.
I guess this is already enough for the packages not to be available.

Moreover, the first line of the file states `# Created by Octave 4.2.1, ... 08:19:23 2017 GMT <unknown@unknown>`, as if it did not exist prior to my installing `symbolic`.

**Questions**:

Q1: **Is there any way to make the packages available?**
I guess I could install each of them, but I also guess that is not the way the `.zip` provided is intended to be used.

Q2: **Why would there be no `octave_packages` provided?**

---

PS: Inspired by [this old link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=516772), I checked if there was an `octave_packages` somewhere else in the tree... there is none.

PS2: Clarifications called for given a comment:
I did not do anything other than expanding the original zip file, and installing `symbolic`. The answers are then implied, but I make them explicit anyway.

*Where did you install the rest?* I did not do it; they were built into the `.zip`.

*How did you try to install them?* I did not.

*Why are you not installing via forge?* Because I already had the installer for symbolic downloaded.

*Did you try setting a local_list in the same way as global_list (and as described in help pkg)?* I did not set or try to set either `local_list` or `global_list`.

*Have you tried creating an octave_packages file yourself?* No. It was created automatically upon installing `symbolic`.

*Did you set a pkg prefix before installing?* No.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43451951/4183191  Having said that, we need more info. How did you install symbolic? Where did you install the rest? How did you try to install them? Why are you not installing via forge? Did you try setting a `local_list` in the same way as `global_list` (and as described in `help pkg`)? Have you tried creating an `octave_packages` file yourself? Did you set a pkg prefix before installing?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - I had already read that post and answers prior to posting here. Please see updated question.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks for clarifying. That makes more sense.

Comment: Just to be clear: After a fresh install on windoze with the MXE installer, have you run `pkg load symbolic` before trying to use the symbolic package? Background: the installer nowadays ships with prebuilt binary octave-forge packages so there shouldn't be a need to "rebuild"

Comment: @Andy, the installer works as intended, but he's talking about the 'extractable' version. In that one, while the package folders are physically there, there does indeed seem to be a need for `pkg rebuild` before all the available packages can be detected through `pkg list` / `pkg load`. Having said that, the symbolic package doesn't seem to be one of the packages installed by default, it seems that OP had downloaded the `.tar.gz` file and installed that separately.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou - This is exactly the case.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Ah, I've overlooked that he mentioned "portable version" in the text. I think it's just ".octave_packages" missing in the home dir, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do

`pkg rebuild`

From the documentation:

> ```
> 'rebuild'
>       Rebuild the package database from the installed directories.
>       This can be used in cases where the package database has been
>       corrupted.
> ```

Once you do this, you should see all packages listed with the `pkg list` command and you can load them as necessary.

Having said that, I would encourage you to report this as a bug to the octave bug tracker (if it's not there already), since, I agree, this is unlikely to be the  desired first-run experience (it certainly isn't via the `.exe` installer). Someone must have forgotten to include a valid, pre-generated `octave_packages` file, which as you point out is missing from the zipfile.

Comment: @sancho.s my pleasure. Did you submit a bug report, or should I? :)

Comment: Please do it. Thanks.

Comment: Submitted as [bug #51632](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?51632)

Answer (score 5):

This is detailed in the [Wiki](https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows):

> If you instead installed Octave from the .zip archive, you need to first rebuild the package list on your local machine. (The command above will produce a blank output and packages will be inaccessible before rebuilding.) Do this by typing the following command:
>
> `pkg rebuild`

It has been this way since v4.01 according to [an earlier mailing list discussion](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-4-0-1-Windows-zip-file-needs-pkg-rebuild-missing-octave-packages-file-td4675844.html). According to the person making the primary Windows build,

> the installer execute "pkg rebuild" in the windows console.
>   For zip version, you need execute by yourself.

So this is a known issue with the 'portable' windows version. I cannot comment on whether there's a particular reason (size?) not to have the `pkg rebuild` done prior to zipping and releasing. There doesn't seem to be a good way to relay this issue/instruction to the user and it has created confusion before.

I could not find an associated bug, so one could be submitted to http://bugs.octave.org, it would at least formally track the issue even if there's no maintainer side interest in fixing it.

EDIT:  there is now a bug related to this issue:  [Octave Bug #51632](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51632)

Comment: I googled quite a bit, and did not get that wiki linked.

Comment: currently link #4 for an 'octave windows' search.  but yes, the curse of using Wiki's for primary instructions is they're sort of hit-or-miss in that regard.  I did notice the octave wiki didn't actually link the windows instructions from it's front page 'install instructions' list, so i'm sure that didn't help.

Comment: ... and #1 with "octave portable windows empty octave_packages", which is similar to what I searched for. I do not know how I missed it (it would have been much faster than going through SO).

Comment: I suppose the path is hardcoded in the `octave_packages` file and needs to be 'generated' on the target machine, so it can't be just a generic file included with the zipfile. I agree though, it could at least be mentioned in the README file, or better yet, on the notices that get launched on first run, rather than expect users to think of searching obscure corners of the octave wiki as their very first experience. (redirecting users to the wiki through the README / launch notice is a decent compromise I guess)

Comment: from previous versions where you had to run a particular package building script, it seems that no one reads the README instructions :)   that said I do know that the 'first run' dialog only happens the first time you run octave on a machine. You don't see it if you delete and 'reinstall' a zip version, or upgrade to a newer version. I hadn't seen it in years until a recent hard drive crash, and that spanned the versions that did and didn't require the `pkg rebuild`.  In any case, I think the discussion probably warrants bug-tracker discussion.