# Octave: Installing package not successful

Tags: octave, package

Trying to install the package communications-1.2.1.tar.gz on my windows-64-system leads to the following error message. What do I have to do to get it running?

```
genqamdemod.cc: In function 'octave_value_list Fgenqamdemod(const octave_value_list&, int)':
genqamdemod.cc:39:23: warning: 'int empty_arg(const char*, octave_idx_type, octave_idx_type)' is deprecated (declared at C:\Program
s\Octave\include\octave-4.2.1\octave\../octave/utils.h:58): use 'octave_value::is_empty' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   int arg_is_empty1 = empty_arg ("genqamdemod", nr1, nc1);
                       ^
genqamdemod.cc:39:57: warning: 'int empty_arg(const char*, octave_idx_type, octave_idx_type)' is deprecated (declared at C:\Program
s\Octave\include\octave-4.2.1\octave\../octave/utils.h:58): use 'octave_value::is_empty' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   int arg_is_empty1 = empty_arg ("genqamdemod", nr1, nc1);
                                                         ^
In file included from galois.h:24:0,
                 from galois-def.cc:21:
C:\Programs\Octave\include\octave-4.2.1\octave\../octave/config.h:28:2: warning: #warning "config.h has been deprecated; there is n
o need to include it directly" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "config.h has been deprecated; there is no need to include it directly"
  ^
In file included from galois-def.cc:21:0:
galois.h:25:28: fatal error: octave/base-lu.h: No such file or directory
 #include <octave/base-lu.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [galois-def.o] Error 1
make: Entering directory `/tmp/oct-2OnYWD/communications-1.2.1/src'
C:/Programs/Octave/bin/mkoctfile-4.2.1.exe -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES __errcore__.cc -o __errcore__.oct
C:/Programs/Octave/bin/mkoctfile-4.2.1.exe -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES __gfweight__.cc -o __gfweight__.oct
C:/Programs/Octave/bin/mkoctfile-4.2.1.exe -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES cyclgen.cc -o cyclgen.oct
C:/Programs/Octave/bin/mkoctfile-4.2.1.exe -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES cyclpoly.cc -o cyclpoly.oct
C:/Programs/Octave/bin/mkoctfile-4.2.1.exe -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES genqamdemod.cc -o genqamdemod.oct
C:/Programs/Octave/bin/mkoctfile-4.2.1.exe -DGALOIS_DISP_PRIVATES -c galois-def.cc -o galois-def.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/oct-2OnYWD/communications-1.2.1/src'

pkg: error running `make' for the communications package.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 95 column 9
    install at line 192 column 7
    pkg at line 394 column 9
```

The following table shows the result of pkg list.

Package Name         | Version | Installation directory
   ---------------------+---------+-----------------------
               control  |   3.0.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\control-3.0.0
        data-smoothing  |   1.3.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\data-smoothing-1.3.0
              database  |   2.4.2 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\database-2.4.2
             dataframe  |   1.1.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\dataframe-1.1.0
                 dicom  |   0.1.1 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\dicom-0.1.1
             financial  |   0.5.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\financial-0.5.0
                  fits  |   1.0.7 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\fits-1.0.7
   fuzzy-logic-toolkit  |   0.4.5 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\fuzzy-logic-toolkit-0.4.5
                    ga  |  0.10.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\ga-0.10.0
               general  |   2.0.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\general-2.0.0
         generate_html  |  0.1.13 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\generate_html-0.1.13
              geometry  |   2.1.1 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\geometry-2.1.1
                   gsl  |   2.0.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\gsl-2.0.0
                 image  |   2.6.1 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\image-2.6.1
    instrument-control  |   0.2.3 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\instrument-control-0.2.3
              interval  |   2.1.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\interval-2.1.0
                    io  |   2.4.5 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\io-2.4.5
        linear-algebra  |   2.2.2 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\linear-algebra-2.2.2
                  lssa  |   0.1.2 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\lssa-0.1.2
                 ltfat  |   2.2.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\ltfat-2.2.0
               mapping  |   1.2.1 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\mapping-1.2.1
         miscellaneous  |   1.2.1 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\miscellaneous-1.2.1
                   nan  |   3.1.2 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\nan-3.1.2
                netcdf  |  1.0.11 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\netcdf-1.0.11
                 nurbs  |  1.3.10 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\nurbs-1.3.10
                   ocs  |   0.1.5 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\ocs-0.1.5
                odepkg  |   0.8.5 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\odepkg-0.8.5
                 optim  |   1.5.2 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\optim-1.5.2
            quaternion  |   2.4.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\quaternion-2.4.0
              queueing  |   1.2.5 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\queueing-1.2.5
                signal  |   1.3.2 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\signal-1.3.2
               sockets  |   1.2.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\sockets-1.2.0
             sparsersb  |   1.0.2 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\sparsersb-1.0.2
               specfun  |   1.1.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\specfun-1.1.0
               splines  |   1.3.2 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\splines-1.3.2
            statistics  |   1.3.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\statistics-1.3.0
                   stk  |   2.3.4 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\stk-2.3.4
               strings  |   1.2.0 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\strings-1.2.0
                struct  |  1.0.14 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\struct-1.0.14
                tisean  |   0.2.3 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\tisean-0.2.3
                   tsa  |   4.4.5 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\tsa-4.4.5
                 video  |   1.2.3 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\video-1.2.3
               windows  |   1.2.4 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\windows-1.2.4
                zeromq  |   1.2.1 | C:\Programs\Octave\share\octave\packages\zeromq-1.2.1

Comment: What have you done? The Octave MXE Installer 4.2.1 already includes communications-1.2.1 so you don't have to "side-load" it

Comment: No, I have to install all packages manually (see modified question). But I must admit that I am not sure, whether I used the MXE Installer, alas. Must have been octave-4.2.1-w64-installer.exe from https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html.

Comment: Again: the installer https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/octave-4.2.1-w64-installer.exe includes many, many forge packges, have a look at the README

Comment: The result of pkg list is shown in the question. Only the manually installed packages are visible. I can see many other packages in share/octave/packages, but they seem not to be installed. So there might have been a problem during installation of Octave (but without any warning or error message).

Comment: ... >> pkg list
If you instead installed Octave from the .zip archive, you need to first rebuild the package list on your local machine. (The command above will produce a blank output and packages will be inaccessible before rebuilding.) Do this by typing the following command:

  >> pkg rebuild

Comment: Great! Now the list is much longer, but it is still missing the communications package. I tried to put it into the question, but the system does not get my formatting correctly. Perhaps s.o. could correct this.

Comment: Since you've tried to build communications yourself, the package was uninstalled as first step. I would really suggest to uninstall Octave, delete all related folders and make a new install using the MXE installer without trying to sideload packages

Comment: Ok, many thanks. I will try to do so (although I do not have any admin rights on this pc, so I am not sure, whether it will work).

Comment: if you're using the zipped version, you don't need admin rights since everything simply gets unzipped in a normal folder on your desktop. Also see [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45413796/4183191) for cross-reference. It's a common issue.

Comment: Yes, it is running already. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

I believe just a re-installation will do --> https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/#install

following the instructions exactly.

Comment: There is also an official binary installer for Windows released -->https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/news/release/2019/03/01/octave-5.1-released.html