# Windows Octave socket package install error

Tags: sockets, octave, scilab

I'm a newbie regarding to `Octave` and FYI I'm using windows.
I want to install the sockets package to have `Sci cosim`, a sort of `Simulink` with `Octave` and `scilab`. This can be seen in [Sci cosim](https://wiki.octave.org/Sci_cosim).

I tried multiple times to install the sockets package but there is always an error.
When I try to implement the package with: `pkg install -forge sockets` I get error:

> a sh with a long path and an error: pkg: error running `make' for the
>   sockets package. error: called from
>       configure_make at line 99 column 9
>       install at line 184 column 7
>       pkg at line 441 column 9

If I download the package, put it into the directory and do install the package by: `pkg install sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz`
the error is:

> pkg install sockets-1.2.0.tar.gz error: urlwrite: unable to open file error: called from pkg at line 431 column 33

I really have no clue what to do ( installed and uninstalled `Octave` multiple times (with reboot) )

Thanks for helping

Comment: which octave are you using? are you using the usual installer, or unpacked a zipfile? have you checked with `pkg list` that the package isn't installed already? have you performed a `pkg rebuild` if it's from a zip?

Comment: for the record, `pkg install -forge sockets` works well for me on linux and octave 5.1.0

Comment: I'm using octave 5.1.0 I did not perform a pkg rebuild, I don't understand why I should perform a pkg rebuild

Comment: if you have a normal octave installation you don't have to. If you obtained the 'portable' version, you may have to perform some post-install steps for each machine you use it, as per [the wiki](https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows) (and also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45399494/4183191) ). I don't think this is your issue, but since you gave no information on this I thought I'd mention it just in case.

Comment: Have you checked `pkg list`? It's weird you don't have `sockets` already, since in theory it comes pre-installed with the normal windows installer.

Comment: I have checked the pkg list but there is no socket package

Comment: if you're not installing from a .zip, and you have no packages pre-installed, then I would encourage you to report this on the octave bug tracker and see what they say.

Comment: I have packages, this is not the problem. The problem is that I always get error codes when trying to install the sockets package.

Comment: How are you running octave? from a shortcut from the installer, or by running a .a bat or .vbs or .exe file ?

Comment: @lostbard I'm running Octave forme the exe file on gnu.org (octave-5.1.0-w64-installer.exe). FYI I've installed octave on my C drive directly in a file called octave, this to make sure I don't have accents or special characters in the path of the directory.

Comment: @Jemery, if (after install) you are running the octave-gui or octave-cli.exe directly, then don't. You need to run it from the bat or vbs file which sets up additional paths and environment settings in order for octave to run correctly.